# How can I remove the method arguments from a method declaration from a source code file and write it back?

Tags: python

I have a .txt file that contains pre-processed source code. It looks like this:

```
public static <V, E> E addEdgeWithVertices(Graph<V, E> g, V sourceVertex, V targetVertex)
g.addVertex(sourceVertex);
g.addVertex(targetVertex);
return g.addEdge(sourceVertex, targetVertex);
```

I want to get rid of the method arguments in the first line(method declaration) i.e. `Graph<V, E> g, V sourceVertex, V targetVertex` and write this back to my same file.

This is my code, it doesn't seem to work:

```
with open('source_code.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        match_parameters = re.search("(public|protected|private|static) .*\((.*)\)", lines[0])
        remove_parameters = 
        match_parameters.group(0).replace(match_parameters[2], "")
with open('source_code.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(remove_parameters)
```

Actual Output(remaining lines are missing):

```
public static <V, E> E addEdgeWithVertices()
```

Expected Output:

```
public static <V, E> E addEdgeWithVertices()
g.addVertex(sourceVertex);
g.addVertex(targetVertex);
return g.addEdge(sourceVertex, targetVertex);
```

Comment: What is the actual output you get?

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey updated!

Comment: You only call `re.search` on `lines[0]`, so `match_parameters` and, in turn, `remove_parameters` are only the first line.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey So how do I replace that first line while maintaining the other lines as they are?

Comment: If you call `re.search` on all of the lines, it should still only match the first line, and leave the rest of them as-is.

Comment: Error:  `return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: That's because `lines` is a list and `re` is expecting a string. Try `re.search(..., "\n".join(lines))`

Comment: Still printing only the first line. I tried `match_parameters = re.search("(public|protected|private|static) .*\((.*)\)", "\n".join(lines))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that it will always be in the first line, you can do:

```
import re

with open('source_code.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        match_parameters = re.search("(public|protected|private|static) .*\((.*)\)", lines[0])
        remove_parameters = match_parameters.group(0).replace(match_parameters[2], "")
        lines[0] = remove_parameters + "\n"
with open('source_code.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines("".join(lines))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be searching all the lines. And don't forget to add the original line whenever search returns `None`.

```
clean_code = []
with open('source_code.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        match_parameters = re.search("(public|protected|private|static) .*\((.*)\)", line)
        if match_parameters is not None:
            clean_code.append(match_parameters.group(0).replace(match_parameters[2], "") + "\n")
        else:
            clean_code.append(line)
with open('source_code.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(clean_code)
```

However, use [Calvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56531893/3201403) if in fact the replacement has to be done only on the first line.